# Auth laravel 6 con Vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, laravel-6

Estoy inmerso en una aplicación en laravel 6 y Vue con un template que he comprado (Vuexy) que ya viene preparado con toda la estructura y dependencias.

La instalación es correcta pero cuando quiero implementar la autorización para comenzar con el login de los usuarios, estoy teniendo problemas con Mix.

En laravel 6 para implementar Auth se ejecutan las siguientes órdenes:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Tras ejecutar, instalar dependencias y compilar assets `npm install && npm run dev` lanzo la aplicación y obtengo el error de Mix:

`Unable to locate Mix file: /css/main.css.`

Antes se cargaba correctamente el dashboard por defecto de la plantilla pero ahora no soy capaz de resolver.